# How to properly start gpg-agent on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: gnupg, gpg-agent

I have a Yubikey4 loaded with my gpg-key, acting as a smartcard. I can do `gpg2 card-status` and it gives me the whole shebang showing all my subkeys and everything is fine.

I then wanted to use gpg-agent to ssh into remote hosts using my gpg key. I added the following to my `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

```
enable-ssh-support
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-curses
default-cache-ttl 60
```

I also set the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in my .bashrc as this:

```
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh
```

If I then reboot my machine, the key is added and visible with `ssh-add -l`

```
4096 SHA256....... cardno: ..... (RSA)
```

But any attempts to ssh to a remote server just hangs, `ssh -vvv` tells me the machine tries to sign and send the key, but the agent refuses operation.

If I then execute a script I made using various sources it all works.

```
   killall gpg
   export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh; gpg-agent --daemon --keet-tty --use-standard-socket --pinentry-program=/usr/bin/pinentry-curses
```

I tried implementing this using bashrc, executing it with my deskopt-manager and a user systemd task to no avail.

Can anybody help me figure out how to start this automatically on login, without  the need to execute "my script"?

Comment: The one little thing I could think of is make sure that all your gpg related agents are all the same version. I notice you're running `gpg2` as the command, and with killall gpg resolving the issue, my naive assumption is that either scdaemon or gpg-agent is an old version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer :**

Execute as root :

```
$ echo enable-ssh-support >> ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf
# editor /etc/X11/Xsession.options
    ... comment out "use-ssh-agent" ...
# aptitude purge libpam-gnome-keyring
```

Logout off your desktop session and login again,
and check that $SSH_AUTH_SOCK is pointing at your gpg-agent.

**Explanation :**

By default, the gpg-agent doesn’t enable its SSH agent.
This is done either by passing `--enable-ssh-support` on the command-line
or by adding a line to a configuration file as above.

Second, the problem of other SSH agents.
The OpenSSH agent starts by default, set up by
`/etc/X11/Xsession.d/90x11-common_ssh-agent` from the x11-common package.
If running GNOME, the GNOME Keyring agent is running as well.
Both of those will interfere with our GnuPG agent.

Disabling the OpenSSH agent is by editing `/etc/X11/Xsession.options` as above.

Disabling the GNOME Keyring agent is potentially a bit more complicated.
Using Xfce, one can un-install the libpam-gnome-keyring package
and ensure that Xfce doesn’t start GNOME services
(*Settings → Session and Startup → Advanced → Launch GNOME services on startup* – untick if ticked).

**Troubleshooting**

If after all this SSH_AUTH_SOCK is still not pointing at your gpg-agent,
you may have another agent still interfering with your GnuPG agent.
The SSH_AGENT_PID variable should contain the PID of the agent process,
which will help to pinpoint that agent.

Source :
[My Perfect GnuPG / SSH Agent Setup](https://www.bootc.net/archives/2013/06/09/my-perfect-gnupg-ssh-agent-setup/#Linux:_Starting_the_correct_agent_at_login)

Answer (score 0):

Put the script in `/etc/profile.d`. Make sure you executable bit set (`chmod +x`) and the file has a `.sh` extension.

Comment: Why? What does this do exactly?

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#A.2Fetc.2Fprofile.d.2F.2A.sh